# DocuSign API - Update Template PDF Document

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have an existing DocuSign Template setup and working well. I would like to be able to update the PDF file used for the Template via the API using a locally stored PDF file that I have. Is there a way to update the PDF file used by the DocuSign Template via the API?

I can see that you can update a Template here:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/Templates/update

but can't work out what I need to do to replace the PDF file with a new one?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to update the PDF file used by the DocuSign Template via the API?

Yes. You use the compositing templates API feature to substitute a document for the existing one in the "server template" (a template stored on the server).

See [DocuSign Rest API to replace single template document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129814/docusign-rest-api-to-replace-single-template-document) for a code example.

> (From a comment)
>
> How do I update the template's definition to use a different document?

See the [TemplateDocuments::update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/TemplateDocuments/update) API method.

Comment: Just to clarify I don't want to send an envelope with the new PDF file, I'm just looking to replace the PDF for a Template with a new PDF, similar to  using the Replace option in the Web UI. Is it possible to replace a PDF only without sending an envelope at the same time?

Comment: Ohh, you want to modify the template so that it now uses a newer version of the document? See my updated answer.